# How to return a class variable as a reference (&/ampersand) in PHP?

Tags: php, function, variables, ampersand

This is sample of my code.

```
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass
{

    function __construct($input)
    {
        parent::__construct($input);
        $this->conn = new mysqli('a','b','c','d');
    }

    function getConnection()
    {
        return &$this->conn;
    }

}
```

My main object is that i want to return the MySQLi connection by referencing it instead of creating another MySQLi class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

```
function &getConnection()
{
   return $this->conn;
}
```

and when calling:

```
$conn = &$instance->getConnection();
```

That's how to [return variables by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) in general, but for [`resource` type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) variables you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. This is the first time i see "&" in function name :P

Comment: I edited the question for more clarification, and yes php is weird : )
Don't forget to mak accepted answers as accepted.

Comment: I was waiting for the time limit to pass to accept as answer. Thanks i accepted.